# How do I create a table using inputs from a user, the amount of which changes depending on a previously specified input from the user?

Tags: c

I am not allowed to use arrays. I need to list all of the course codes, days, and times for as many courses as the user has specified in the first scanf_s call. I have no idea how to proceed without using arrays. Any help hint/help would be appreciated.

```
printf("Please enter the number of courses you'd like to take: ");
int numOfCourses;
scanf_s("%d", &numOfCourses);
int courseCode;
int courseDay;
int courseTime;

int i = 0;
while (i < numOfCourses) {
    printf("Please enter the code of the course: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &courseCode);
    printf("Please enter the day of the course: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &courseDay);
    printf("Please enter the time of the course: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &courseTime);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic memory allocation in a linked list. Look at `malloc`. Your list structure could look like:

```
typedef struct COURSES {
    int courseCode;
    int courseDay;
    int courseTime;
    struct COURSES *next;
} t_Courses;
```

You allocate a list element as follows:

```
    t_Courses *pCourse= malloc(sizeof(t_Courses));
```

and then read the data as you do now, e.g.:

```
    scanf_s("%d", &pCourse->courseCode);
```

Managing a linked list is not simple. I leave it to you as part of the homework. There are numerous examples on the internet and on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! One thing regarding the syntax of your code I don't understand is "->". How does that work in this code: 

    scanf_s("%d", &pCourse->courseCode);

Comment: '->' is for accessing 'courseCode' field of 'pCourse' pointer to struct.